# 'Logon attempt failed'

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have set up an ESX server running various operating systems for some testing/educational needs.  Two VM's are Windows Server 2012 & 2016 and I cannot RDP to either of them from my desktop.

I have remote desktop enabled on both and tried logging on using [hostname]\administrator but I get a 'Logon attempt failed' no matter what I do.

I can RDP from server to server, but not from my Windows 10 (home) desktop.  Tried disabling firewall etc, but nothing.

Comment: @CConard96 You have that backwards. Windows home can be an RDP client (you can RDP to other computers), but not an RDP server (other computers can't RDP to you).

Comment: What is the exact error you get form the RDP client?  Have you setup your Host<->VM networking correctly?  Can you contact the VM's form the desktop via other methods (like Ping)?

Comment: To be clear, I am trying to RDP onto either Windows Server 201x from my Windows 10 Home desktop.  I know that Windows X Home won't allow incoming RDP (grumble).  It returns an error saying that the credentials did not work.

Comment: Also, the VM's are using addresses assigned by my BB router.  I have a Linux appliance for example and can easily access via ssh and it's application UI via HTTP.  Yes I can ping and RDP obviously connects but just doesn't accept the credentials in the various forms I have tried.

Comment: When you say "[hostname]\administrator" are you specifying the target server as the "[hostname]"?

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't know what has happened, but for some reason it is working now.  I changed the administrator password to something simpler (after easing the password requirements) and rebooted the servers and lo, I am able to connect from my desktop.

Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a local server. I was able to logon to the VM via the VM console but NOT VIA REMOTE DESKTOP.
I changed the connection name to the IP address.
I was then able to connect.
Once connected, I changed the DNS entries & remove an OLD DNS server & that seemed to have resolved the issue.